Использование белого айпи вместо домена RocketChat
прошу сильно не кидаться помидорами касательно сетевой части почти полный профан, есть задача развернуть свой сервер RocketChat используется эта инструкция (https://vk.com/@rocketchat-install-rocketchat-420-on-ubuntu-2004-lts), но нет домена, возможно ли использовать наш белый айпи, для примера 13.13.13.13 и куда именно его вписывать в конфигурационный файл

Там ведь написано: После Rocket.Chat будет доступен по адресу: http://ip-host:порт [порт по умолчанию 3000]

домен в зоне .ru стоит чуть больше 100 руб.
